# How to prevent "App is draining battery" notification

Tags: android, android-location, android-background

We have a driving behavior monitoring app that requires gathering location and sensor data from phone in background when the user is driving a vehicle. We take the requisite permissions from user during onboarding to be able to access Location All the time. We also optimise the data collection to reduce battery consumption.

Still, some of our users get a sporadic message generated by Android that our App is draining the battery.

Is there any Android documentation that defines the criteria on when such a notification is shown. If the user ignores the notification, will it still keep coming. Is there anything a developer can do to prevent that notification from popping up.

Thanks